# SQL Query returning thousands of empty rows

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a table with ~180,000 rows currently. I have a query:

```
SELECT `item_id`, COUNT(*) AS Count FROM `user_items` GROUP BY `item_id`
```

which runs on a table with columns: 'combination_id', 'user_id' and 'item_id'. There are roughly 6000 `item_ids` and of course 180,000 `combination_id`s as mentioned.

I want to return the number of occurrences of each item_id. When I run this query in phpmyadmin I get 180,000 rows in the result but most of which are empty (as there are only 6000 or so unique item_ids).

Could anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: It is happening because there are 180,000 distinct `item_id`.  Perhaps they contain characters that you cannot see, but they are distinct.

Comment: @GordonLinoff that's not quite the case. I'll edit my question to be more precise but there are 180,000 distinct user_id - item_id combinations (which have an id). i.e. many users can 'own' 1 item (of which there are 6000 or so). I'm looking for the number of occurrences of each `item_id` ignoring user information

Comment: Is that the exact query that you are running? As far as I can tell it would give you exactly the result that you are after. What does the rows that are empty contain? Do they have an `item_id`? Do they have a value for `Count`? Do they contain empty strings, zero, or null values?

Comment: That's the exact one. It says "Showing rows 3850 - 3874 (185228 total, Query took 0.0700 sec)" and on that page (155/7410) there is no longer a 'next page' button however I can select next page with a dropdown and from there no 'rows' are visible, just columns.

Comment: Strangely enough when exported as CSV it is as required so for my purposes that's fine. Odd thing to happen in phpmyadmin though :)

Comment: Possibly, your index statistics are out-of-date (or missing - you _do_ have indices, right?), and the admin page is attempting to use optimizer information to build paging which is getting bad data for that.